# PHP set a default value for database insert

Tags: php, mysql

I have a number box `<input type='number' step='any' name='number' id='number'>`

and I take that value and call it in a function like so:

`insertIntoDB($number)`

```
function insertIntoDB($number = null){

  //insert into db
  "INSERT INTO 'tablename' (number) VALUES " . $number;

}
```

and I get this error:

```
Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' '
```

Is there away so if the user leaves the field blank it will enter the value as null?

Comment: Remove the quotes for `'tablename'`

Comment: That isn't even close to valid PHP code. Plus you have unnecessary quotes around your table name.

Comment: @Fred-ii- great minds think alike :-)

Comment: @JohnConde Si signore ;-)

Comment: Wh you will enter a record without informations? or has the table more informations? If ou want to insert null just write it into $number

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set default values when creating the table itself, but apart from that, the code you pasted is missing some brackets:

```
INSERT INTO `tablename` (number) VALUES (" . $number.")";
```

If you want to use a NULL when inserting and get a default value in the table, you can do it when creating the table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE test 
    (
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    someField VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'on'
    )
```

Now when you try to insert data into it, you can do the following:

```
insert into `tablename` (id, someField) values (null, null)
```

and get a row with an incremented ID and the string 'on' in the column `someField`.

If you want to check for nulls when inserting data into a table, you can then use something like the following to ensure you have the value:

```
$someField=(isset($number))?$number:'null';
INSERT INTO `tablename` (number) VALUES (" . $someField.")";
```

This is assuming you have already verified that $number is either numeric or isn't submitted when sending the form.